# sessionStorage["key"] vs. sessionStorage.setItem("key")

Tags: session-storage

I am trying to use sessionStorage in my application. I saw that when I use sessionStorage["key"], the key disappears once I call: location.href="http://etc.."; so when I try to type sessionStorage, I don't find my key there.

But the key remains there if I use sessionStorage.setItem("key"), anyone knows the difference between both of these ways?

Answer (score 1):

[There is no difference:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

> These three lines all set the colorSetting entry in the same way:
>
> ```
> localStorage.colorSetting = '#a4509b';
> localStorage['colorSetting'] = '#a4509b';
> localStorage.setItem('colorSetting', '#a4509b');
> ```

Comment: But am talking about sessionStorage here. I tested it, with sessionStorage[""], values didn't stay after the page was posted back to another page. while sessionStorage.setItem did it

Comment: but the linked page refers to all storages - `sessionStorage` should behave the same; are you sure that you didn't have website opened in another tab?

Comment: No, it's the same browser.